# SQOOP-IMPORT : create-hcatalog-table vs create-hive-table

Tags: sqoop

I am trying to do a sqoop-import into hive database.

I would like to know the difference in these two available options

create-hcatalog-table vs create-hive-table

```
sqoop-import    
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hadoopexample    
--table employees  
--create-hive-table  
--fields-terminated-by ','  
;
```

vs

```
sqoop-import    
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hadoopexample    
--table employees  
--create-hcatalog-table  
--fields-terminated-by ','  
;
```

Comment: I think this is not a Sqoop question, you just want to know the difference between HCatalog and Hive. Check this: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/224734/how-hcatalog-is-different-from-hive.html

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear. hope its sqoop related now